# Mina deploy: I have set up SSH, but can't connect to git@github.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, ssh, mina

I try to deploy a private repository using [mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/).

I have generated a public SSH key on my server which I then added to my GitHub user. Being logged into my server, I can do a `git clone git@github.com:Access4all/a4aa2.git`. But from my local machine, when executing `mina deploy`, I get the following error:

```
-----> Loading environment        
-----> Creating a temporary build path        
-----> Fetching new git commits        
       Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
       Permission denied (publickey).
       fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.   
-----> Cleaning up build
```

What looks strange to me is the fact that the IP `192.30.252.130` is added to the list of known hosts, although I already did this before when manually ssh'ing. And the IP of my server is `192.30.252.130` (bellatrix.uberspace.de)!

My `deploy.rb` config section looks like this:

```
set :server_name, 'bellatrix'
set :user, 'a4aa2'
set :repository_name, 'a4aa2'

set :domain, "#{server_name}.uberspace.de"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/rails"
set :repository, "git@github.com:Access4all/#{repository_name}.git"
set :branch, 'master'
```

Did I conceptually understand something wrong?

**Update**

I just noticed that the passphrase is aked when doing a manual git clone:

```
[a4aa2@bellatrix tmp]$ git clone "git@github.com:Access4all/a4aa2.git"
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/a4aa2/tmp/a4aa2/.git/
Enter passphrase for key '/home/a4aa2/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I guess that Mina fails because of this. Is this normal? Why do I have to enter the passphrase? How can I circumvent it?

**Update**

According to [Step 3: Add your key to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-3-add-your-key-to-the-ssh-agent), I can save the passphrase to ssh-agent.

But it seems that I'm somehow not able to save it the way it's described there.

I can add it like this:

```
[a4aa2@bellatrix tmp]$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/a4aa2/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/a4aa2/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/a4aa2/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

And then I can successfully clone the repository without entering the passphrase. But after logout and login again, I have to enter it again. Somehow the ssh-agent doesn't seem to work between session?

Comment: deploy.rb looks fine. Did you try git cloning manualy on the server? you ssh configuration with github seems iffy...

Comment: I updated the previous answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out that I don't need a private/public key pair on my hoster, because I can simply activate the `forward_agent` option of mina:

```
set :forward_agent, true
```